# Abort trap: 6 Error on mac (C)

Tags: c, macos, codeblocks, osx-yosemite

I always get abort trap error while doing my code homework. I have looked everywhere on the internet but I haven't found anything that helped with my problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int i, j, k;
double fin_raw[4][2], f[4], bt[2][4], x[4];

printf("Input all y values:");
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    scanf("%lf", &f[i]);
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    printf("%lf\n", f[i]);

printf("Input all x values:");
for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    scanf("%lf", &x[j]);
 for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    printf("%lf\n", x[j]);

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    fin_raw[i][0] = pow((x[i]), 2);
    fin_raw[i][1] = x[i];
    fin_raw[i][2] = 1;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x` and `f` only have four elements. You're trying to store 5 elements.

Comment: @Mat thank you so much! I thought that since array indices start at 0, an array which has a total of 5 elements has a size of 4.